# C: Linked List via Pointers, The build keeps failing for some reason

Tags: c, linked-list

I coded a basic linked list working by pointers. It has functions for creating, inserting, deleting, and finding nodes according to positions.
For some reason, the build output says

```
1>Done building project "Linked List.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There are no errors unfortunately, so I don't understand what's the problem.

Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

struct node *head = NULL;

void PrintList()
{
    struct node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

node* New(int data)
{
    node *new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    new->data = data;
    new->next = NULL;

    return new;
}

void Create(int data)
{
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;

    node *new = New(data);
    temp->next = new;
}

void Insert(int data, int position)
{
    struct node *temp1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    if (position == 0)
    {
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }
    struct node *temp2 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    for (int i = 0; i < position - 2; i++)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        temp2->next = temp1;
    }
}

void Delete(int position)
{
    struct node *temp1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));

    if (position == 0)
    {
        head = temp1->next;
        free(temp1);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < position - 2; i++)
        temp1 = temp1->next;

    struct node *temp2 = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    free(temp2);
}

int Find(int position)
{
    struct node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    for (int i = 0; i < position + 1; i++)
        temp = temp->next;

    return temp->data;
    free(temp);
}

void menu()
{
    printf("Linked List in C \n\n");
    printf("1.Create an element\n");
    printf("2.Insert as the kth element\n");
    printf("3.Delete the kth element\n");
    printf("4.Find the kth element\n");
    printf("0.Exit\n");

}

int main()
{
    int command;
    int data;
    int position;

    head = NULL;

    menu();
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a command (0~4):");
        scanf("%d", &command);

        if (command == 0)
            break;
        switch (command)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a number to be created as the last element: \n");
            scanf("%d", data);
            Create(data);
            PrintList();
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a number to insert into the list: \n");
            scanf("%d", data);
            printf("Enter the position to insert this element: \n");
            scanf("%d", position);
            Insert(data, position);
            PrintList();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter the position of the element to be deleted: \n");
            scanf("%d", position);
            Delete(position);
            PrintList();
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Enter the position of the element you are looking for: \n");
            scanf("%d", position);
            int X = Find(position);
            printf("The element in node %d is %d. \n", position, X);
            PrintList();
            break;
        }

    }
    //dispose(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Among those who think that casting `malloc()` is a good thing, and those who think that it's dangerous, now I see something new `struct node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));`, note that you are using the same type both sides of the expression, but I had to go to `struct node`'s definition in order to know that. Don't cast at all, and you can avoid some problems in fact.

Comment: You're missing the error messages.  That's peculiar.  You need to spend time working out why you're not seeing the compilation errors — restarting the build process or whatever.  It looks like you're probably using MS Visual Studio on Windows.  Wholly separately, I see a problem in the `Find()` function, you end `return temp->data;
    free(temp);` — that `free()` will never be executed.  However, that probably isn't enough to stop the code compiling under default options.

Comment: `scanf("%d", foo)` -> `scanf("%d", &foo)`.

Comment: Although someone here could try to compile the code and identify the error for you, you should try to check why isn't your IDE telling you anything useful. Try compiling this from the command line and check there.

Comment: Note that the mistake pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547656/c-linked-list-via-ponters-the-build-keeps-failing-for-some-reason#comment80049715_46547656) does not necessarily prevent compilation.

Comment: `head` is never initialized to anything but zero, in `PrintList` you allocated memory (why) but in `create` you don't, and many more problems. About everything in this program is wrong. Maybe you should read the chapter dealing with pointers, and linked list again.

Comment: I think the problem is in you Visual Studio settings.  I was able to compile  your code successfully both on Linux (using gcc, version 4.8.4) as well as on Windows (using Visual Studio 2015).  In each case I did get a number of warnings like: "format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]"; but they wouldn't stop a compilation.  However, your program does seg-fault on running.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much for the comments! I guess i should study more before going anywhere from here....

Comment: I compiled the posted code using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11`   The result was 15 warnings.  So, 1) the posted code does not cleanly compile.   2) What did you use for your link command?

Comment: in the `Delete()` function there is this statement: `struct node *temp1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));`   WHY?  Per the name of the function, deleting a node, not creating a node.

Comment: the function: `PrintList()` is total nonsense. it is creating a node, then (without even setting the values in that node, trying to print the fields.)  Suggest something similar to: void PrintList( struct node *head )
{
    struct node *temp = *head;   // get pointer to first node--
    while (temp != NULL)            // while not past end of nodes--
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;          // step to next node--
    }
    printf("\n");
}